# How to collect an electron project in one portable file?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

How should I take the electron project (example [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start)) into one portable executable file for Windows?

I tried electron-builder and electron-packager, but it built an executable that depended on other files.

Comment: One piece of advice: Although you have already built your application for Electron, I advice taking the time to switch to Tauri. It's REALLY compact, secure, and fast. I love it and.. .although switching languages is difficult, it's worth it. Definitely look into it too.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, at the time of choosing the framework, I knew about Tauri, but I still chose Electron because I already had practice with it (but did not get to the project assembly).

Comment: @PinBlb That's still a great choice! Although I can't help you unfortuntely, I wish you the best with your application. Keep up the good work!